# Javascript Weird Bug (?)

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

While coding, I came across something weird in Javascript. I'm not sure it's a bug. Maybe I just don't know why it happens but it looks really weird to me, so I made a simplified example of it. Here it is.

I have this code:

```
var v = 0.01;
for(var i=0;i<21;i++){ 
    if(i % 4 == 0 && i!=0){
        v += 0.01;
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to be true:

```
v == 0.06;
```

What is actually true:

```
v == 0.060000000000000005;
```

Can someone explain why I get this instead of what I'm expecting? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at floating point precision.

Comment: ... it is not a bug see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: It is common "problem" with floating point numbers. Use `toFixed(2)` to *fix* the problem.